# Is it safe to add inheritance relationship for a pickled object?

Tags: python, pickle

I have some old pickle files that store object `d`:

```
class D():
  def __init__(self, val):
    self._val = val

  def val(self):
    return self.val

d = D()
pickle.dump(d, file_store_obj_d)
```

Now, I want to do some refactor and add a base interface class for `D`:

```
class B():
  def val2(self): # new interface
    return self.val()+1
  
  def val(self):
    pass

class D(B):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self._val = val

  def val(self):
    return self._val

d = pickle.load(file_store_obj_d) # is this safe and keeps backward compatibility?
```

I want to know is code above safe?(`B` is an interface class having no new attributes, only some new methods are added)

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? You can pickle and unpickle this object, that should work, but you could have found that out by simply trying, right? Is there more to your question?

Comment: @zvone the above example works and `d.val2()` gives the correct result. My main concern is will there be any other use case that could break the code and give undesired results if doing so